# How do I get the AR cards on the digital download version via 3ds?

Tags: bravely-default

I have a 3dsXL. I purchased/downloaded the game Bravely Default via the E-Shop.  When starting the game, it mentions something about an AR card.  Is it possible for me to obtain that AR card(s) with the digital version of the game? What is this and how do I obtain them via the digital download version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can print them out from here:

[Bravely Default AR Cards](http://bravelydefault.nintendo.com/ar-cards/)

They are effectively like QR codes that the 3DS can understand.  The 3DS will turn on your front facing cameras to show you what is behind your 3DS and superimpose a 3D model where you placed the card.  You can also move your 3DS around and get a different perspective of the 3D model.

`AR` stands for "Augmented Reality"

Side note, I think the game restricts the view angle you can get on the models because:

> I can't see up any of the costume's skirts.